# Is it worth making a CMS from scratch?

Tags: php, security, content-management-system

I am about half way through coding my own Php Content Management System from scratch, but now I am nearing the end of coding new features and making it look good and am now being faced with the big issue of security. I know little about the security side of Php except the fact that it is very vulnerable with SQL injection etc. Let's just say my website was going to have loads of user generated content and be like facebook, is that something one person could secure by themselves or am I better off paying someone to do it for me? if so, anyone know how much that would cost?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Update:
Any opinions on http://www.incapsula.com ?

Comment: Trust nobody - especially anonymous people! Therefore inject into you mayor asset some safe data. Seems rather wise strategy.

Answer (score 8):

With so many mature PHP CMS systems available, the only reasons I can think of for writing one of your own would be as an exercise (to learn something), as a challenge (to see if you could), or if you needed some specific feature that the existing ones didn't have. Even if you did want a special feature, I'd still look at extending an existing CMS rather than writing one from scratch - many of them cater for modules and / or plug-ins.

Comment: I like the idea of making something new, the way I want, doing only and exactly what I want, but I must consider the fact that already available systems are designed to have extreme customisability for people like me. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 8):

Pros:

- It is fun to build your own CMS.
- You will learn a lot. It might be the best way to learn PHP, since you will have to deal with a lot of different aspects of it.

Cons:

- Your first CMS will always have a "funny" design.
- You will have bugs and security holes (but most of the times, people will not notice the security holes). ;)
- You will have to spend (much) more time on your CMS than what it would take to build the site with an existing CMS.

Conclusion:

- Of course you shoud build your own CMS! You are not a real PHP programmer if you never have built your own CMS.

Comment: Agreed, have you built your own?

Comment: Yes, a couple of them. :) It kept me going for a couple of years. However, nowadays a almost always use WordPress for everything.

Comment: Having fun building a CMS - You need to get out more! Anyway it might be a good way of learning programming.

Comment: You might get a partner?! By daughter is sleeping and my boyfriend is sleeping off the chocolate egg

Answer (score 3):

> Is it worth it?

Completely up to you. I'd say it depends on what your goals are with this CMS (generating revenue, just for fun, etc) It's nice to be able to show someone and say "I made that from nothing!"

The only start up costs would be your domain name and monthly web hosting (unless you hire people.) $1.18 annual for a godaddy domain, $8 for hostmonster hosting.

Security's a big issue yes, but maybe that shouldn't be the deciding point in doing what you want or not. There's alot of documentation on stackoverflow and others regarding the subject that could help you.

I've recently created a CMS from scratch with no prior knowledge of anything beyond basic HTML. It's rewarding in many ways and you may even find yourself going down a programming career path.

Comment: Did you do security on your CMS?

Comment: Yeah, I did everything myself. If you choose the path of creating your own, I'd start by googling "CSRF Forgery." That should get you off on the right foot.

Comment: Is your CMS online at the moment?

Comment: Yes. You can view it at www.no-crew.com.

Comment: That's a nice CMS although do you deal with user generated content?

Comment: Yeah, users are able to input data onto the server for public viewing. Notice the three links at the bottom of the main page. Thank you for the compliment!

Comment: I see, do you get much spam? or does that email verification process stop most of it?

Comment: Pretty much. I'm guessing the email verification and captcha stops alot of spam. I haven't seen any yet, but I've only recently made the site public. Spamming would probably get tiresome very quickly with this setup, plus there's no benefit other than to be a nuisance.

Comment: Fair enough and What about people just posting ads?

Answer (score 3):

I think it'd be better to learn how to protect your system. Securing php systems is actually not that big a deal, considering you were able to code your system from scratch.

Just remember, to prevent sql injection: always escape user input entered to the database, `mysql_real_escape_string()` usually does the job. And use `htmlentities()` before displaying the content in html pages.

Read on securing your PHP and you'll save yourself the trouble of paying someone to do it, plus it'll help on other projects.

Comment: Im just considering the fact that sites like Facebook and Twitter have huge security systems constantly updating and improving, which makes me wonder how one person could learn to do it.

Comment: Facebook is a big site, yours is just the size of a pea **by now**. Just follow common tips on preventing such attacks and your site is good to go. Hackers won't work their ass out on small websites unless they have grudge on you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is worth making a CMS from scratch. Because you have/only have the features that you only need. Which makes the script less extensive and fit your needs **like an Armani suit**. Let's consider Wordpress as an example, when your site gets terribly big you would need to terribly tweak it. It has alot of features, and **some of them you might not need**. The pro if using already-available ones is *the community finds the script's bug/holes for you* and all you need to do is just update the script.

As for the security part, you can try to find the holes by yourself or hire someone of which their rates may vary. But you might not want to entrust your script to others unless they're trustworthy.

Comment: Yea I love coding it myself making it do what I want, how I want.

Answer (score 2):

Trust nobody - especially anonymous people! Therefore inject into you mayor asset some safe data. Seems rather wise strategy

Why make your own CMS? Drupua, wordexpress. Jomala might do with some tweaks?!

Comment: I want to make my own so it does exactly what I want, not changing someone else's code into something that does what I want. Although it has served me well using Joomla etc for other projects, I'm not sure about this project.

Comment: @McDanGarrett - Why spend the effort? You AS A PERSON CAN achieve more, a lot more, by not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That's a very good point, but I can achieve even more if was able to successfully reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: @McDanGarrett - I be interested. Please write a spec first. Otherwise you will not know where this ship is going.

Comment: A specification means that you can spend time to think it out. Without that you are just sailing into the wind